# Method Reference for Integer type List

Tags: java, string, list, java-8, java-stream

I have code like below.

```
List<Integer> parameters = ...

String string = " NOT IN (" + 
    parameters.stream()
              .map(parameter -> parameter.toString())
              .collect(Collectors.joining(",")) 
+ ") ";
```

I want to convert parameter -> parameter.toString() lambda expression to method reference.

Comment: `String::valueOf` would do I think, but some SQLs allow a PreparedStatement `NOT IN(?)` with an SQL Array: connection.createArray. That would be vendor dependant, but nicer IMO.

Comment: `String string = parameters.stream() .map(Object::toString) .collect(Collectors.joining(",", " NOT IN (", ") "));`

Answer (score 2):

Just define a `toString` method in the your class, say `Parameter`, and you can use it as a method reference in streams:

```
parameters.stream().map(Parameter::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(","))
```

If you don't have a specific class, and you are using `Integer` type for the list, just use directly `Object::toString` as suggested by collegues in the comments.

My answer meant to cover the general case, that is the one which handles user defined classes with any method.

Comment: There is no `Parameter` class in the example — it's a list of `Integer`s. However, `toString()` is defined on `Object`, so either `Integer::toString` or `Object::toString` will be fine.

Comment: Agree with @ohlec. Please edit your answer to the following - 
    parameters.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(","))

Comment: `Integer::toString` won't work because of overloads, but `Object::toString` will work fine.

Comment: @talex Ah, I see — because of Integer's static `toString` variant creating ambiguity.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The source is `List<Integer> parameters`. The OP works with the `List<Integer>` not with `List<Parameter>`.

Comment: @Nikolas Read it completely

Answer (score 1):

Since the `parameters` is `List<Integer>` you would probably need:

```
parameters.stream().map(i -> i.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

**Problem**

However, using the reference method is a bit problematic since the `Integer` has defined three methods called `toString`:

- [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString--) which returns a String object representing this Integer's value.
- [`static toString(int i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString-int-) which returns a String object representing the specified integer.
- [`static toString(int i, int radix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString-int-int-) which returns a string representation of the first argument in the radix specified by the second argument.

So the usage of method reference like below will result in:

```
parameters.stream().map(Integer::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

> Ambiguous method reference: both toString() and toString(int) from the type Integer are eligible

**Solution**

In this case, you can use the class `Number` which is a parent of `Integer` and its method [`Number::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) which does exactly the same:

```
parameters.stream().map(Number::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: Does my answer contain anything incorrect? I'd welcome a feedback and a reason of a downvote...

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
List<Integer> parameters = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);

    String string = parameters.stream()
            .map(Object::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", " NOT IN (", ") "));
System.out.println(string);
```

It's not need to concat `String`, `Collectors.joining` do that for you.

Result:

```
NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```